# Replaying Messages in Order

Tags: node.js, azure, rabbitmq

I am implementing a consumer which does processing of messages from a queue where order of messages is of importance. I would like to implement a mechanism using NodeJS where:

1. the consumer function is consuming messages `m1, m2, ..., mN` from the queue
2. doing an IO intensive operation and process the messages. `m -> m'`
3. Storing the result `m'` in a redis cache.
4. acknowledging the queue after each message process (2)

In a different function, I am listening to the message from the cache

- sending the processed messages `m'` to an external system
- if the external system was able to process the external system, then delete the processed message from the cache
- If the external system rejects the processed message, then stop sending messages, discard the unsent processed messages in the cache and reset the offset to the last accepted message in the queue. For example if `m12'` was the last message accepted by the system, and I have acknowledged `m23` from the queue, then I have to discard `m13'` to `m23'` and reset the offset so that the consumer can read and start processing from `m13` again.

[image]

**Few assumptions:**

- The processing `m` to `m'` is intensive and I am processing them optimistically, knowing that most of the times there won't be a failure

With the current assumptions and goals, is there any way I can achieve this with RabbitMQ or any Azure equivalent? My client doesn't prefer Kafka or any Azure equivalent of Kafka (Azure Event Hub).

Comment: The major issue of trying to enforce order or processing and large scale ingestion like Azure Event Hubs is that to do so comes at a cost. If the node is too slow in accepting a request should the sender fail and retry, should the attempt be discarded or should it be sent to another node where it is potentially processed before the previous message that was holding everything up? If you can design a sender that is resilient in that it can ignore a failed send and retry, then there is potential to enforce a processing sequence at the hub level, otherwise you will need to re-sequence messages

Comment: The more I think about this, you have probably abstracted this too far in your explanation, having two consumers processing at different rates and trying to tell one consumer to reset back to a previous state would mean that you would have to persist the previous data for a potentially long time.

Comment: How many message producers are there in this scenario?

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris for considering this problem. There can be multiple message producers. For simplification, I would consider there is one producer. Because I cannot load balance here, because the order matters. For the matter of persisting the data, it wont be more than a day or so. I am expecting messages in the order of hundreds per second. I have considered storing the order in a separate DB and using that for replaying but that doesn't seem like an elegant solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

In scenarios where the messages will *always* be generated in sequence then a simple queue is probably all you need.

[Azure Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-queues-introduction) are pretty simple to get into, but the general mode of operation for queues is to remove the messages as they are processed successfully.

> If you can avoid the scenario where you must "roll back" or re-process from an earlier time, so if you can avoid the *orchestration* aspect then this would be a much simpler option.

It's the "go back and replay" that you will struggle with. If you can implement two queues in a sequential pattern, where processing messages from one queue successfully pushes the message into the next queue, then we never need to go back, because the secondary consumer can never process ahead of the primary.

---

With *Azure Event Hubs* it is much easier to reset the offset for processing, because the messages stay in the bucket regardless of their *read* state, (in fact any given message does not have such a state) and the consumer maintains the offset pointer itself. It also has support for multiple consumer groups, which will make a copy of the message available to each consumer.

> You can up your plan to maintain the data for up to 7 days without blowing the budget.

There are two problems with Large scale telemetry ingestion services like *Azure Event Hubs* for your use case

1. The order of receipt of the message is less reliable for messages that are extremely close together, the Hub is designed to receive many messages from many sources concurrently, so its internal architecture cares a lot less about trying to preserve the precise order, it records the precise receipt timestamp on the message, but it does not guarantee that the overall sequence of records will match exactly to a scenario where you were to sort by the receipt timestamp. (its a subtle but important distinction)
2. Event Hubs (and many client processing code examples) are designed to guarantee Exactly Once delivery across multiple concurrent consuming threads. Again the Consumers are encouraged to be asynchronous and the serice will try to ensure that failed processing attempts are retried by the next available thread.

So you could use Event Hubs, but you would have to bypass or disable a lot of its features which is generally a strong message that it is not the correct fit for your purpose, if you want to explore it though, you would want to limit the concurrency aspects:

- minimise the partition count

  > *You probably want 1 partition for each message producer, or atleast for each sequential set, maintaining sequence is simpler inside a single partition*
- make sure your message sender (producer) only sends to a specific partition

  > Each producer MUST use a unique partition key
- create a consumer group for each of your *consumers*
- process messages one at a time, not in batches
- process with a single thread

---

I have a lot of experience in designing MS Azure based solutions for Industrial IoT (Telemetry from PLCs) and Agricultural IoT (Raspberry Pi) device implementations. In almost all cases we *think* that the order of messaging is important, but unless you are maintaining real-time 2 way command and control, you can usually get away with an optimisitic approach where each message and any derivatives are or were correct at the time of transmission.

If there is the remote possibility that a device can be offline for any period of time, then dealing with the stale data flushing through the system when a device comes back online can really play havok with sequential logic programming.

Take a step back to analyse your solution, EventHubs does offer a convient way to rollback the processing to a previous offset, as long as that record is still in the *bucket*, but can you re-design your logic flow so that you do not have to re-process old data?

What is the requirement that drives this sequence? If it is so important to maintain the sequence, then you should probably process the data with a single consumer that does everything, or look at chaining the queues in a sequential manner.